# Batch - Error reading File path from Properties file

Tags: java, batch-file, properties, cmd

I'm using java to Store a directory path to Properties file.
And then in the bat file I'm using the Property as variable.
The problem is in `Java` the file path is stored as

`SOME_VAR=D\:\\Madhan\\Program Files\\XXX\\bin`

in the properties.

Note the `\:` after the drive name.Its causing a problem when read in batch file.I'm using the below bat script to refer

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%G IN (config/config.properties) DO (set %%G=%%H)  
java -cp xxx.jar;%SOME_VAR% xpackage.yclass
```

If the value is like this

`SOME_VAR=D:\\Madhan\\Program Files\\XXX\\bin`

then it's working fine

Is there a way in java to store without that escape character or
How to replace the `\:` with `:` in bat

Answer (score 1):

```
set "somevar=%some_var:\:=:%"
```

[more info](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)